# parallels accessing arbitrary port on host OS from guest OS

Tags: parallels, toad

I'm running Windows 7 inside of Parallels on Mac OS X 10.7.5. No firewalls have been setup.

From the Mac end, to work remotely I need to VPN into my corp network. Then I use SSH Tunnel Manager to set up tunnel ports on my localhost (the Mac), specifically for connecting to an Oracle database. In my case, I start up the tunnel bound to port 21001 locally and then run SQLDeveloper and connect to localhost:21001. Fine, no problems.

Now I want to run Toad in Windows and use the tunneled port on the host Mac OS, but I can't seem to get this working. I did an ifconfig (Mac) and a ipconfig (Windows) and see the following:

Mac:

```
en1: inet 192.168.1.8
vnic0: inet 10.211.55.2
vnic1: inet 10.37.129.2
```

Windows:

```
IPv4 Address 10.211.55.3
Default Gateway 10.211.55.1
```

In Toad when setting up the DB connection I tried connecting to 10.211.55.2:21001 (just as I set it up in SQLDeveloper on the Mac, but using the host's IP address provided by Parallels). This didn't work. Just for the heck of it I tried using the default Gateway address and also the IP address my router assigned the Mac 192.168.1.8. None of these IP addresses work.

Can anyone please advise on what the issue might be?